# A limit involving the Regularized Incomplete Beta Function

Tags: limits, special-functions, beta-function

I'm trying to evaluate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^{n-1}I\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}; \frac{n+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $I(x; a, b)$ is the [Regularized Incomplete Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html) and $-2\leq x \leq 2$, and I'm stuck on where to begin. I've tried expanding the beta function as the quotient of two integrals and then differentiating using L'Hopital's rule, and I've tried using a series representation for the Beta function, but nothing seems to work. I've tried plotting this function of $x$ with $n=199999$ [using WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+199999*x%5E199998*Beta(1-x%5E2%2F4,+100000,+1%2F2)%2FBeta(100000,+1%2F2)+from+0+to+2), and because of the result I strongly suspect that it tends to $0$ everywhere but $x=\sqrt{2}$ where it tends to $\infty$, but I can't seem to prove this. How would I start?

Comment: your second hyperlink is the same as your first... I presume you meant it to link to Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Fixed.

Comment: I believe your limit is equal to $$=\frac{\Gamma(\pi/2)}{\sqrt 2}\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{3/2}x^{n-1}\;B\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}; \frac{n+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$$ and [graphical evidence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+100000%5E(3%2F2)*x%5E99999*Beta(1-x%5E2%2F4,+100001%2F2,+1%2F2)+from+0+to+2) suggest I am right. Note however that the Beta function is fighting really hard to overpower the other terms, and so the function is very sensitive to conditions... small graphical errors or floating point errors could throw off a visual argument easily.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen How did you come across this result, and how would you evaluate the limit from there?

Comment: From the simple fact that, for large $x$ and fixed $y$, $B(x,y) \sim \Gamma(y)x^{-y}$. Note that the value $x=\sqrt{2}$ yields zero; Simply note that $B(0,a,b)=0$ for positive $a,b$

Comment: Based off of the above, I would presume your limit is identically zero. I'm not too familiar with the Incomplete Beta Function, but I got the solution to $$\frac{\Gamma(\pi/2)}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left({1/2 \choose k}(-1)^k(4-x^2)^{k+1/2}2^{-2k}\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{3/2}x^{n-1}\frac{(4-x^2)^{n/2}}{2^n(2k+n+1)}\right) $$ (assuming all my arithmetic is corrrect)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I was able to use your asymptotic for $B(a, b)$, and one that Wolfram gives for $B(x; a, b)$, to fully evaluate the limit. I'd appreciate if you'd read over my answer and let me know if I messed up anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found an answer, but I would appreciate if someone would check to see if I did this correctly before I mark this question as answered.

Under [Series formulas for the Incomplete Beta Function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/06/01/03/01/01/), Wolfram gives that

$$B(z; a, b) \propto \frac{z^a}{a}\left(1+O(z)\right)$$

and under [Approximation for the Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation) Wikipedia gives that

$$B(a, b) \propto \Gamma(b)a^{-b}$$

when $a$ grows and $b$ stays fixed (credit to Brevan Ellefsen for finding this second approximation). Because of these two approximations we can write our limit as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^{n-1}\frac{C\frac{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

where $C$ is some constant not depending on $n$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^{n-1}\frac{C\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2}}}$$

$$c\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}x^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$$

for some other constant $c$.

Let $x = 2\sin\theta$. The limit then becomes

$$c\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(2\sin\theta\right)^{n-1}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{n+1}$$

$$c\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)^{n-1}\cos^2\theta$$

$$c\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(\sin\left(2\theta\right)\right)^{n-1}\cos^2\theta$$

Note that, whenever $\left|\sin\left(2\theta\right)\right| < 1$, the $\left(\sin\left(2\theta\right)\right)^{n-1}$ term tends to $0$ more quickly than the $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ term tends to $\infty$ (since $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is asymptotically a power of $n$ and $\left(\sin\left(2\theta\right)\right)^{n-1}$ is exponential), and the limit is just $0$; also note that when $\left|\sin\left(2\theta\right)\right| = 1$ the limit tends to $\infty$. Thus, this reduces to the problem of finding $\theta$ such that

$$\sin^2\left(2\theta\right) = 1$$

$$4\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta = 1$$

$$x^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right) = 1$$

$$4x^2-x^4 = 4$$

$$x^2 = 2$$

$$x = \pm\sqrt{2}$$

So, at these points the limit tends to $\infty$ whereas everywhere else it tends to $0$.

Comment: I've read through this a couple times now. That asymptotic formula for the Incomplete Beta Function is beautiful... I saw it while looking for an appropriate formula yesterday,  but thought that the term on the right was dependent on $O(b) $... That will teach me to double check!! Overall the proof is gorgeous. I would note that,  and correct me if I'm wrong, you are restricting the domain of $x$ with the substitution to $[-2,2]$. While this domain is large enough to prove the explosion to infinity at $\pm \sqrt 2$, it is not enough to prove that the function is zero outside of this Interval.

Comment: I thus think that you need handle the cases $(-\infty, -2)$ and $(2,\infty) $ separately and show that the limit vanishes everywhere on these intervals. I would also justify that the $\sin(2\theta)^{n-1}$ term vanishes more quickly than the $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ term grows. Other than those small details I think this proof is one of the greatest I've seen. The sinusoidal substitution was a great insight. +1 on this answer!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I only really cared about the case where -2<x<2 (specifically 0<x<2) which is why I didn't specifically address the other cases. I'll edit the question to make that clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That makes sense. Out of curiosity, what was the context behind this question?? In the future I would add this to the main body of the post... I was very hesitant myself to do much with this problem, and only spent a bit on it due to the lack of post content. Of course, the reason could simply be curiosity, which is perfectly reasonable and even admirable in its own right - I just thought I would ask. I would still make sure to justify that $\sin(2\theta)^{n-1}$ decays faster than $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I just fixed that; is it clear enough?  The context behind this question is that it's related to the distribution of distances between points in $n$-space, and I was curious to see what happened in the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I would definitely say it's clear enough now. I would accept it. Did you work out the formula yourself or is there a link to the derivation? I'm quite curious.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I worked it out with a few others. I can let you know when (or if) we publish it.